# Debian: Unable to connect to ssh with a user I just created

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, root

I've a debian 6 installed on a server.

I installed ingres on this server, which runs now with the user "ingres", I want to connect to ssh with the ingres user(for many reason, one of them is that when I do "su ingres", it seems that commands stored in .profile file are not executed).

The user has a /home/ingres folder, bash as console, but when I try to connect I got an "Access denied" error.

When I created the user I didn't specify any user, so I ran the

> usermod -pThePasswordHere ingres

and I'm sure that I'm using the same password to connect to ssh.

But I still get my errors:

```
login as: ingres
ingres@192.168.xxx.yyy's password:
Access denied
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
passwd username
```

and then type in the password for the user name.

Also make sure that the password your are entering is correct by typing it slowly. Sometimes I jumple up some letters in my password, so thats a possibility.

Make sure that ingres was added to the ssh users as well.

Comment: I just found the same solution, it seems that usermod -pThePassword ingres wasn't working!

With passwd it's okay

Comment: glad i could help

Comment: J4N: `usermod -p` requires encrypted password as an argument so unless you are hardcore enough to encrypt passwords real time in your head, that is not a recommended way for setting up passwords. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the password command to set the password for a user. If you want to script setting the password, take a look at chpasswd.

What you did when you used usermod -p to set the password was to overwrite the *crypted* password as it's written in /etc/shadow, so what you would have needed to do to set your password to ThePassword with usermod would have been:

```
usermod -p '$6$f2ob/Bhg$EPzlpkg7INdDxeuisOXOffKJddbLUFXdHLe6V7dFUQccLQ2CX9Pu2I8WJam2uZY4peh8EHHeLwwMW5mW3cHwz/' password
```